# Text Rendered over bitmap

Tags: android

I 'd like to know how can I render a text over a 48x48 bitmap in my android application, considering sometimes the text exceeds the bitmap width .In such cases I need to render only a part of the text followed by dots such that all fits the available width !

Thanks !

**Update**, Here's the code I used:

```
    Bitmap renderSurface = icon.createBitmap();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(renderSurface);

    Paint paint  = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(10);
    if(paint.measureText(nativeName)>canvas.getWidth())
        nativeName = getClippedString(paint,nativeName,canvas.getWidth() );

    canvas.drawText(nativeName,33,0, paint);

    return renderSurface;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create another Bitmap (unless the original Bitmap is mutable) and then create a Canvas to draw on that Bitmap. Finally, just call drawText() on the Canvas. To know where to ellipsize your text, you can use the Paint's class text measurement methods.

Comment: Could you show me in a snippet how to obtain an instance of the Paint class ?

Comment: Oh !, silly question from me , please ignore it. However I obtain the following error that I can not resolve and don't know what it means : " immutable bitmap passed to canvas constructor"

Comment: Read the Bitmap documentation. You must use one of the copy*() or create*() methods that returns a *mutable* Bitmap. Only mutable bitmaps can be drawn upon.